# Loop Control Structure - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm just starting to learn loops, and in a for loop, if I'm looping through an array, in the second condition, I state that i < arrayName.length.  I don't understand the logic here, surely it should be i = arrayName.length;  Why does the length have to be < (less than) when you're looping through the entire array?

example:

```
var myArray = ['cats', 'dogs', 'monster munch'];

for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  console.log([i]);
}
```

Any explanation would be really useful and I'm guessing this is the same with other javascript loop structures?

Emily.

Comment: Because the index of the last item for an array with  length 3 is 2

Comment: Because the second part of a `for` is the *condition* which, if true, allows the loop to run through one more time.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for Read through the mdn documentation.

Comment: Corresponding Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop

Comment: this for loop is equivalent to `var i = 0; while(i<myArray.length){ console.log(i); i++; }`. And please declare your variable `i`, or it will end up in the global scope.

Comment: in this specific case, you surely could use i != myArray.length as the condition to continue the loop. it all depends on what condition you like to continue the loop. the variable i doesn't have to just increase by 1 at each loop cycle. you can let i to increase by more than 1 at each cycle if so desired. if so, i may never be equal to myArray.length and you'd have a endless loop (but again, that could be what you might want under some circumstances). again the middle part of the for loop is the condition to continue the loop and it's really up to you to set the condition.

Comment: Thanks @Juan Mendes that makes sense now.  If you want to post that as an official answer I'd be happy to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement in the loop initializes i to 0, the second statement is the condition so basically it's saying "while `i` is less than the length... "until the statement is false. The 3rd statement is increment.

Comment: Yes I understand the context, I just don't understand why it uses i < myArray.length  when you are looping through the entire array? Surely is should be true all the way up the i equalling the array's length, not being less than?

Comment: How would it know you're looping through the entire array? and not say another array in the same file? Futhermore, in your example you aren't exactly looping through the array, you're just repeating some tasks over until the condition is no more true. If you wanted to loop through the array you'd use `for(x in myArray){do something}` @EmilyChewy

Answer (score 0):

The statement in the middle is what is called the "condition". When that statement is `true`, the loop continues. If it is `false` the loop stops.

And yes, in Javascript it is useful to note that it is the statement in the middle. You can have many initializations, and many increments, but the middle one must always be the condition. e.g.

```
for (var i=0; var j=10; i != j; i++; j--) {  // do stuff }
```

Is a valid for loop with two variable declarations and two increments. It will stop if `i == j`